# how do I display a custom form windows workflow custom activity

Tags: c#, .net, windows, workflow

Is it possible to show a windows form when implementing a custom activity?

For instance, how do I show a custom form, when a user double-clicks on my activity in the designer?

Or perhaps a custom form could be displayed when a user clicks the ... in the properties selection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not to sure if that can be done.

For any interaction required with my custom activities I would create a number of dependency properties which would appear in the properties window for the custom activity when it gets dragged onto the designer.

e.g. From property for custom email activity

```
public static DependencyProperty FromProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("From", typeof(string), typeof(SendMailActivity));

[DescriptionAttribute("The email of the sender")]
[CategoryAttribute("Parameters")]
[BrowsableAttribute(true)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
public string From
{
    get
    {
        return ((string)(base.GetValue(SendMailActivity.FromProperty)));
    }
    set
    {
        base.SetValue(SendMailActivity.FromProperty, value);
    }
}
```